# How to create a general method for Scala 3 enums

Tags: scala, enums, scala-3

I want to have a simple `enumDescr` function for any Scala 3 enum.

Example:

```
  @description(enumDescr(InvoiceCategory))
  enum InvoiceCategory:
    case `Travel Expenses`
    case Misc
    case `Software License Costs`
```

In **Scala 2** this is simple (`Enumeration`):

```
def enumDescr(enum: Enumeration): String =
  s"$enum: ${enum.values.mkString(", ")}"
```

But how is it done in **Scala 3**:

```
def enumDescr(enumeration: ??) = ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any common trait shared by all `enum` companion objects.

You still can invoke the `values` reflectively, though:

```
import reflect.Selectable.reflectiveSelectable

def descrEnum(e: { def values: Array[?] }) = e.values.mkString(",")

enum Foo:
  case Bar
  case Baz

descrEnum(Foo) // "Bar,Baz"
```

Comment: Seems like an improvement to be made

Comment: The compiler is making structural changes (adding methods) that are not reflected in the nominal type system (no common trait), so, yeah...

Comment: Minor clarification: There is a common trait - `scala.reflect.Enum`, but since Scala 3 compiler does not generate `values` or `valueOf` for enums with parameters, that trait does not declare those methods, since they are not common for all possible cases.

Answer (score 11):

##### Java Reflection

If you declare your `enum` as Java-compatible, you can use Java reflection to get the array of its values using the `Class.getEnumConstants` method.

To declare a [Java-compatible `enum`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/enums/enums.html#compatibility-with-java-enums) it has to extend the `Enum` class:

```
enum Color extends Enum[Color]:
  case Red, Green, Blue
```

You can use `getEnumConstants` on the static class to get correctly typed `Array` of values:

```
val values: Array[Color] = classOf[Color].getEnumConstants
```

But if you want to use it in a generic manner, I believe you have to cast the `Class` or the `Array` to the correct type with `asInstanceOf`:

```
def enumValues[E <: Enum[E] : ClassTag]: Array[E] =
  classTag[E].runtimeClass.getEnumConstants.asInstanceOf[Array[E]]
```

Subtype declaration `<: Enum[E]` is not strictly needed there, but is used  to avoid calling it with unrelated classes and causing runtime exceptions.

Now a method `enumDescr` can be written in a similar way:

```
def enumDescr[E <: Enum[E] : ClassTag]: String =
  val cl = classTag[E].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[E]]
  s"${cl.getName}: ${cl.getEnumConstants.mkString(", ")}"
```

And called like this:

```
scala> enumDescr[Color]
val res0: String = Color: Red, Green, Blue
```

##### Scala compile-time reflection

If you want just the names of the enum cases, you can get them using `scala.deriving.Mirror` (thanks to @unclebob for the idea):

```
import scala.deriving.Mirror
import scala.compiletime.{constValue, constValueTuple}

enum Color:
  case Red, Green, Blue

inline def enumDescription[E](using m: Mirror.SumOf[E]): String =
  val name = constValue[m.MirroredLabel]
  val values = constValueTuple[m.MirroredElemLabels].productIterator.mkString(", ")
  s"$name: $values"

@main def run: Unit =
  println(enumDescription[Color])
```

This prints:

```
Color: Red, Green, Blue
```

##### Scala 3 macro for a sequence of values

You can use Scala 3 macro to generate the call to `values` on the companion object.

Macro definitions from the same file can't be called, so the macro has to be placed in a separate file:

```
/* EnumValues.scala */

import scala.quoted.*

inline def enumValues[E]: Array[E] = ${enumValuesImpl[E]}

def enumValuesImpl[E: Type](using Quotes): Expr[Array[E]] =
  import quotes.reflect.*
  val companion = Ref(TypeTree.of[E].symbol.companionModule)
  Select.unique(companion, "values").asExprOf[Array[E]]
```

Then in the main file:

```
enum Color:
  case Red, Green, Blue

// Usable from `inline` methods:
inline def genericMethodTest[E]: String =
  enumValues[E].mkString(", ")

@main def run: Unit =
  println(enumValues[Color].toSeq)
  println(genericMethodTest[Color])
```

Comment: can getting the actual enum values, rather than the label strings, be done generally using compile time ops? it seems that enum cases aren't constant types, so can't be materialized using `constValue`/`constValueTuple`. Also curious why enum cases don't qualify as constant values, if anyone can explain why that is?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an inline def using a Mirror.SumOf[A] which has all the information you need.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/derivation.html

Comment: Could you share a complete code sample matching OP's code?