# How to Pattern Match on Scala 3 enums

Tags: scala, enums, pattern-matching, scala-3

I want to pattern match to the new enum type in *Scala 3*.

With *Scala 2* this is easy, because there is an abstract class `Enumeration`, that you can match on, like:

```
obj match {
  case e: Enumeration => ...
  case other => ...
}
```

How can I achieve this in *Scala 3* as there is no common interface?

From the answers of this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69743692/how-to-create-a-general-method-for-scala-3-enums) I tried:

```
case v: { def values: Array[?] } => ...
```

This compiles with a warning but when I run `publishLocal` it throws an exception:

```
[error] (api / Compile / doc) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: There is a common trait: `scala.reflect.Enum` but what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I need the values of the Enumeration. `def values: Array[?]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I came up:

```
case v: scala.reflect.Enum =>
  val e:{ def values: Array[?] } = v.asInstanceOf[{ def values: Array[?] }]
  e.values.map(_.toString).toList
```

This works and it is possible to publish. Still no idea why it is not possible with `case v: { def values: Array[?] } => ...`

So better solutions and explanations still welcome.