# Method to abstract enum type and its value

Tags: scala, enums, scala-3

I have these two enums:

```
enum Season:
  case Warm, Cold

enum Territory:
  case Continente, Madeira, Açores
```

I want to create a method `radioInputsFor` which receives the enum type and a concrete enum value such that these invocations are valid:

```
radioInputsFor(Season, Season.Warm)
radioInputsFor(Season, Season.Cold)
radioInputsFor(Territory, Territory.Madeira)
```

And these invalid:

```
radioInputsFor(Season, Territory.Madeira)
radioInputsFor(Territory, Season.Cold)
```

I also want to invoke `.values` on the first parameter inside the method.

**What are the correct generics and types I should use for the parameters?**

This

```
def radioInputsFor[T <: Enum](default: T): T = default
```

Correctly restricts the first parameter to be an enum value. However I cannot find a suitable type that abstracts the enum type.

Edit: currently this is not possible. However [this PR](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/14136) is adding the required functionality.

Comment: It appears that the companion of the enum type doesn't extend anything special. Out of curiosity, what is the use-case for accepting both an enum and a companion as parameters? That is, what would you do with `values`?

Comment: I want to create a radio input (in ScalaJS) for each case of the enum (using `values`), the second argument (a specific enum case) would be the radio input that would be checked by default. Receiving the enum type would also allow me to get its name. And I have 3 different unrelated enums for which I want to generate the radio inputs.

Answer (score 1):

As already [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69743692/how-to-create-a-general-method-for-scala-3-enums/69746693#69746693), there currently seems to be no common interface for `enum` companion objects.

You can fall back to reflection:

```
import reflect.Selectable.reflectiveSelectable
def pointedEnum[E <: reflect.Enum](
  companion: { def values: Array[E] },
  value: E
): (List[E], E) =
  (companion.values.toList, value)

def demo() =
  pointedEnum(Season, Season.Warm)
  pointedEnum(Territory, Territory.Madeira)
  // pointedEnum(Season, Territory.Madeira) // Nope
  // pointedEnum(Territory, Season.Cold) // Nope
```

Comment: There is a PR that will eventually fix the problem: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/14136